# What determines whether an event is passed to my function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, events

The argument e will be undefined when called from script embedded in the anchor element.

```
function testOverrideClick(e) {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();          
}

....

<body onload="afterLoad();">
<a id="testAnchor" href="http://www.google.com" onclick="testOverrideClick()">test link</a>
```

However, if I register the event handler from script, e will be valid:

```
function afterLoad() {
      document.getElementById("testAnchor").onclick = testOverrideClick;
}

...

<a id="testAnchor" href="http://www.google.com">test link</a>
```

What's happening?

Comment: You obviously pass nothing to `testOverrideClick()` in your inline event handler. Read on event handling methods [at quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `event` identifier to your function.

```
<a id="..." href="..." onclick="testOverrideClick(event)">test link</a>
```

---

This works because the function assigned in W3 compliant browsers will look something like this:

```
elem.onclick = function(event) {
    testOverrideClick(event);
}
```

So the event parameter will be passed on.

---

And in older IE, it will look more like this:

```
elem.onclick = function() {
    testOverrideClick(event);
}
```

So the global `window.event` will be passed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `window.event` isn't just passed to the function in older IE...you have to normalize it inside the handler function with something like `var evt = e || window.event;` (where `e` is the parameter)

Comment: I had previously tried onclick="testOverrideClick(e) but the argument must be correctly specified as event in order to work so this answer seems most complete.  Javascript seems very inconsistent with how loose or strict your syntax can be.

Comment: @Ian: Why wouldn't it be? The defined handler won't be given a parameter, so the scope chain will be traversed until the global object. Remember, the handler is created automatically.

Comment: @insominx: Any name could be given to the parameter. The browsers have chosen to call it `event`, which is very handy since in IE where there is no parameter defined, it'll pick up the global `event`. In your `testOverrideClick` function, it can still be `e`.

Comment: That appears true for the function definition but not for the embedded onclick="..." in the html element.  It requires that it be called "event" (tested on Chrome).

Comment: @insominx: Yes, that's what I meant. My point was that parameters can be given any valid name. Since the browser is creating the handler function for you, it had to choose a name, so it chose `event`. It's not a question of loose syntax. It's just that developers are allowed to choose their own parameter names, so in your function you can use `e` or `event` or `foobar` or whatever you want. Remember, when inline like that, you're not creating the function... only the function body.

Comment: @thesystem Sorry, what I referring to was when the handlers are bound in Javascript...such as `document.getElementById("id").onclick = funcRef;`. In that case, you aren't specifying the parameters, and normalization of the `event` object is required. But obviously when specifying inline, or using an anonymous function to call the function with parameters, it should work the same as what you're saying. It didn't make sense to me when I commented, but when I realized what I really meant (not directly applicable to your answer), it made sense.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, you're right. In that situation it would need to be manually normalized since the browser isn't creating its own version of the handler for you.

Comment: @thesystem Sorry about the confusion :) I agreed with you in the first place, I was just confused and mixing things up!

Answer (score 1):

> What's happening?

You are not passing anything to the javascript function here:

```
onclick="testOverrideClick()"
```

So your function crashes because you attempt to access the `e` argument which is never passed.

Don't worry, your second code snippet is the correct way to do it - unobtrusively and without mixing javascript and HTML.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: Dunno, I think you nailed it.